# EditText doesn't update

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext

There are 2 fragments there. One of them contains an `EditText` (`fragmentA`).

If I update the `EditText` by calling `EditText.setText()` from another Fragment it doesn't display the newly set text although it has been set as I've set a breakpoint and saw it. It still shows the old text.

The following code is executed in the fragment without `EditText` if user clicks a button:

```
fragmentA.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    editTextInFragmentA.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
  }
}

// Close the fragment
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

What's wrong with this approach? May it be caused by the fact that `fragmentA` is hidden by another fragment when `EditText.setText` is called?

Answer (score 0):

I can realize from the `popBackStack` that your probably using `replace` when placing fragments into their containers. When a `replace` transaction is made, the old fragment gets it's state saved and all of the UI components (`EditText`, `TextView`, `Button`) get their state saved as well. Once the state is saved, the UI components gets destroyed such that trying to reference them after the old fragment has been removed from view will not work (usually causing NPEs if you try to set or change something in them but I'm not sure what's happening in your case). Upon going back to the old fragment using `popBackStack`, the UI is re-inflated within the fragment `onCreateView`, hence you'll have newly created UI component. In case there's an available saved state, it will be used to revert the UI back to when it was before it got replaced with another fragment. Since the text in the `EditText` got saved with the saved state, it was reverted back when you went back to the old fragment, hence setting it from the new fragment doesn't help. This technique is for efficiently using memory hence preventing the app from causing `OutOfMemory` exceptions.

To correct this, the old fragment should contain a callback which the new fragment could call to update the `EditText` value when UI is re-created. The callback would be passed from the old fragment to the new one, and then the new fragment would call this callback and pass it the new string. This new string should be stored first using a global variable inside the old fragment. When the old fragment is re-creating the UI in it's `onCreateView`, check if the global string variable is not null and not empty and hence update the `EditText` using `setText()`.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right direction. However setting the text in onCreateView didn't help. Only when I delegated the task to onResume, EditText showed the right text. I don't know why there is a problem with EditText. There are other controls there which are updated well in onCreateView...

Comment: Probably if it was put last in the `onCreateView` it would work? Since `onResume` will definitely be executed after `onCreateView`, putting it at the very beginning of `onCreateView` and resulting with same text means that there is code after the beginning of the `onCreateVIew` that is probably reverting it back.